# How to use String variables as a condition for looping purpose

Tags: java

I was trying to prepare a flow chart of program for my practice where i encounter that following situation is required for me where a user would enter a string value as input either "Yes"or "Y" and "No" or "N" and based on its input the application would either terminate or restart from a certain point till now i have this as an example in my mind

```
public class ApplicationName {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String restartOperation;
        do {
            restartOperation = Confirm_Before_Exit();
        } while (!restartOperation.equals("No"));

        //Rest of code 
    }

    public static void Some_Operation() {
        //Executed when called before closing application
    }

    public static String Confirm_Before_Exit() {
        Scanner inputData = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;
        System.out.println("Do you want to perform another operation ?" + " " + "Y" + " " + "N");
        answer = inputData.nextLine();
        switch (answer) {
            case "Y":
            case "Yes":
                Some_Operation();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Good Bye !");

        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

This works till the user has not given input as "No" but obviously it wont work if entered "N" or perhaps small "n" or even "no" but for timing i am only trying for "No" and "N" as input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your do while to the following :

```
do {
        restartOperation = Confirm_Before_Exit();
} while (!restartOperation.equalsIgnoreCase("No") && !restartOperation.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

Comment: its again getting into infinite loop and keeps on asking even if entered "n" or  "no"

Comment: @MehulChachada updated the answer. The `||` needs to be replaced by `&&`. Try it out. It works now

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. You make your answer lowercase to take into account cases like YEs, NO, etc. You then specify the n and no.The default should be a catch all.

```
 answer = inputData.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    switch (answer) {
        case "y":
        case "yes":
            Some_Operation();
            break; 
       case "n":
       case "no":
            System.out.println("Good Bye !");
            break;
       default:
            System.out.println("Not a valid reponse");

    }
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer & wouldn't work because in the `do-while` loop, he is checking for `No`. That is what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **Regex** for text matching (it is contained in the default Java-JDK, not an external library). It is extremely powerful.

You define a needle to search for in Regex-syntax, for example this:

```
^no?$
```

It matches text that starts (`^`) with `n` and then eventually (`?`) followed by `o` (but it does not need to be there), after that the text ends (`$`). There's also a flag for case insensitive matching `/i`. You can try `Regex` at *regex101.com*. Try this: [regex101.com/r/edrehj](https://regex101.com/r/edrehj/1)

Okay, how to use this stuff in **Java**? Fairly easy:

```
String input = ...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^no?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // User want's to cancel
    ...
} else {
    // User want's to continue
    ...
}
```

More info at [Wikipedia#Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [Java-API#Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Java-API#Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

You can also put this inside an own method, makes the usage more easy and user friendly to read:

```
private boolean doesUserWantToCancel(final String textInput) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^no?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textInput);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

You then just call the method for your input:

```
...
} while (!doesUserWantToCancel(restartOperation));
...
```

Comment: is there any other way with not using Java API and only using java ?

Comment: Regex is part of the native Java. It's pure Java, you can use it without any external libraries or stuff. Put the above code in your program - it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you want to run `Confirm_Before_Exit()` when you are restarting an operation?

Here is what I would do. Instead of having `string restartOperation` you should have `boolean restartOperation`. This way you either deal with true or false.

In the `Confirm_Before_Exit()` function I would still add the `.toLowerCase()` to your `inputData` to take into account weird cases. I added two booleans `answer` and `inValidAnswer`.

You want your answer to be true if you want to perform another operation. If it is false it will exit.

If the user mistypes, `inValideAnswer` will be set to true and they will get an error saying invalid answer and will get reprompted.

```
public class ApplicationName {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       boolean restartOperation;
       do {
          restartOperation = Confirm_Before_Exit();
       } while (restartOperation);

      //Rest of code 
   }

   public static void Some_Operation() {
      //Executed when called before closing application
   }

  public static boolean Confirm_Before_Exit() {
      Scanner inputData = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean answer;
      boolean validAnswer;

     while(inValideAnswer){ 
        System.out.println("Do you want to perform another operation ?" + " " +     "Y" + " " + "N");
        string userInput = inputData.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        switch (userInput) {
         case "y":
         case "yes":
            Some_Operation();
            answer = true;
            inValideAnswer = false;
            break; 
         case "n":
         case "no":
            answer = false;
            inValideAnswer = false;

            System.out.println("Good Bye !");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("Not a valid reponse");
            inValideAnswer = true;

        }

     }

     return answer;
  }



}
```